# Disable submit button on a page when browser back button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to Disable Submit button(s) on the page when browser's back button is clicked. This should be generic meaning in which ever page I place this  script, it should disable all the Submit buttons on that page when the user hits the browsers back button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that using window.history.pushState and popstate (See below sample). 
For compatibility refer to   [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=history)
For complete documentation refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

                if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

                    window.history.pushState('forward', null, null);

                    $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                       //Add logic here
                    });

                }
            });
```